# PySpark: boolean previous values with conditions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have mydata like this:

```
data = [("110125","James","2021-12-05","NY","PA",60000),("110125","James","2021-12-07","NY","PA",3000),("110125","James","2021-12-07","NY","AT",3000),
            ("5225","Michael","2021-12-25","LA","AT",60000),("5225","Michael","2021-12-17","LA","PA",15000),("5225","Michael","2021-12-17","LA","PA",65000)]
columns = ["id","Name","Date","Local","Office","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
```

Input:

```
   +--------+--------+----------+-----+------+------+
    | id     |Name    |Date      |Local|Office|salary|
    +--------+--------+----------+-----+------+------+
    |  110125| James  |2021-12-05|NY   |PA    | 60000| 
    |  110125| James  |2021-12-07|NY   |PA    | 3000 | 
    |  110125| James  |2021-12-07|NY   |AT    | 3000 | 
    |  5225  | Michael|2021-12-25|LA   |AT    | 60000| 
    |  5225  | Michael|2021-12-17|LA   |PA    | 15000| 
    |  5225  | Michael|2021-12-17|LA   |PA    | 65000| 
    +--------+--------+----------+-----+------+------+
```

I want a new column '`Check`', if one of 4 values `Date, Local; Offfice; Salary` different with previous values and a same `id, name` so True.

Output:

```
+--------+--------+----------+-----+------+------+-----+
| id     |Name    |Date      |Local|Office|salary|Check|
+--------+--------+----------+-----+------+------+-----+
|  110125| James  |2021-12-05|NY   |PA    | 60000|     |
|  110125| James  |2021-12-07|NY   |PA    | 3000 | True|
|  110125| James  |2021-12-07|NY   |AT    | 3000 | True|
|  5225  | Michael|2021-12-25|LA   |AT    | 60000|     |
|  5225  | Michael|2021-12-17|LA   |PA    | 15000| True|
|  5225  | Michael|2021-12-17|LA   |PA    | 65000| True|
+--------+--------+----------+-----+------+------+-----+
```

My code PySpark:

```
df.groupby("ID", "Name").withColumn("Check", F.when((F.col('Local') == F.lag('Local')) |(F.col('Office') == F.lag('Office'))|
                                           (F.col('Date') == F.lag('Date'))|(F.col('salary') == F.lag('salary')), False ).otherwise(True))
```

> AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'withColumn'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use window:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy("id", "name").orderBy("Date")

df = df.withColumn(
    "Check",
    ~((F.col('Local') == F.lag('Local').over(w))
      & (F.col('Office') == F.lag('Office').over(w))
      & (F.col('Date') == F.lag('Date').over(w))
      & (F.col('salary') == F.lag('salary').over(w))
      )
)

df.show()
#+------+-------+----------+-----+------+------+-----+
#|    id|   Name|      Date|Local|Office|salary|Check|
#+------+-------+----------+-----+------+------+-----+
#|110125|  James|2021-12-05|   NY|    PA| 60000| null|
#|110125|  James|2021-12-07|   NY|    PA|  3000| true|
#|110125|  James|2021-12-07|   NY|    AT|  3000| true|
#|  5225|Michael|2021-12-17|   LA|    PA| 15000| null|
#|  5225|Michael|2021-12-17|   LA|    PA| 65000| true|
#|  5225|Michael|2021-12-25|   LA|    AT| 60000| true|
#+------+-------+----------+-----+------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank for your help! 
Can you explain why use 'Date' in orderBy(), please?

Comment: @Cherrycherry Spark DataFrames are unordered so you need to define un orderby clause, otherwise "_previous row_" can be anything. And you probably will get an exception if not used, as `lag` function requires ordering.